# HTML5 datetimepicker addon jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing an issue where by i uses the following addon for jquery date

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

1) I am able to pick a date and time via his example
2) But I did a check and the system does not recognize the string on initial input, it will be undefined until you enter a space '   ' into the textbox.

any advise?

html example

```
<td>Start Time: <input id="startTimePicker" class="textBox" data-ng-model="StartTime" type="text"></input></td>
<td>End Time: <input id="endTimePicker" class="textBox" data-ng-model="EndTime" type="text"></input></td>
```

my script example

```
$(function() {
   $("#startTimePicker").datetimepicker(
   {
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
});

$(function() {
   $("#endTimePicker").datetimepicker(
   {
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it's due to call multiple datetimepicker on multiple input.

Try to add a class in all your input where you want a datepicker.

And init them only one time.

**Example**

```
<input id="startTimePicker" class="textBox datetimepicker" data-ng-model="StartTime" type="text"></input>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker(
   {
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
});
```

Make sure your input are generated before the `datetimepicker()` function. Or you must call the function after they are inserted in the DOM.

Comment: HI! thanks for the reply! I have tested your solution, but it still writes undefined.. I'm changed my # to . and changed the value in my class as well.

Comment: There isn't any error, I did a alert function to check the value upon clicking submit, but the textbox seems to return undefined.

Comment: Your input are generated after the first load of the page ?

Comment: Correct, the page will load first, then i click on the text box to get the datetime and then i click on a button to submit.

Comment: Okay, so make sure you've import Jquery first and datetimepicker library after.